# In what sense is a separable potential maximally non-local?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, locality

A *(rank-one) separable potential* is an operator $V$ with the coordinate representation $$ \langle \mathbf r'  | V | \mathbf r \rangle = - A u(r) u(r')$$ where $u(r)$ is a real-valued function. It is clear that this is not a local potential as it is not proportional to $\delta(\mathbf r - \mathbf r')$, and hence is arguably nonphysical. Nonetheless, separable potentials have found application, particularly in many-body scattering processes in nuclear physics (with interest in their application peaking in the 1960s though they still see some use today). Approximations have been found allowing a generic potential (satisfying some weak assumptions) to be approximated by a separable one for scattering (see e.g. [1]).

This interaction is discussed in Gottfried's classic textbook [2] in section 8.2(b). There it is claimed that this interaction is "maximally non-local". This statement is not explained further. No measure of the degree of non-locality of a scattering potential is presented in the text nor am I aware of any from the literature on separable potentials. How should I interpret this statement? Is it just that the right hand side of the equation has no $\delta$ function term, or is there a quantitative sense in which this potential is more non-local than e.g. one of the form $\langle \mathbf r'  | V' | \mathbf r \rangle= - A u(r) u(r') |\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|^n$ for $n > 0$ (which I would naively think is more non-local)?

*References:*

[1]: C. Lovelace, Phys. Rev. 135, B1225 (1964).

[2]: Gottfried, Kurt, and Tung-Mow Yan. *Quantum Mechanics: Fundamentals*. Springer Science Business Media, 1996.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably more of a comment, but got a bit long and maybe this answers your question already. There is a way to see why a separable potential is in some sense 'the opposite' of a local potential if you think of them as operators acting on a wave-function: the [Hilbert-Schmidt decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_theorem). What this is really saying is that there is a basis of states $|\psi_i\rangle$ in which you can write the operator $V$ in diagonal form

$$ V = \sum_i \lambda_i |\psi_i\rangle \langle\psi_i|.$$

In the position representation this corresponds to

$$ \langle r|V|r'\rangle = \sum_i \lambda_i \langle r|\psi_i\rangle \langle\psi_i|r'\rangle = \sum_i \lambda_i \psi(r)\psi^*(r').$$

The theorem is a generalization of the [Schmidt decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_decomposition) for matrices (which is often used for example in quantum information) to continuous variables. If the theorem can be applied depends on whether the operator is compact, but I will ignore this restriction here since I only want to make a qualitative argument.

For a **separable potential** as defined by the OP, we see that this corresponds to a Hilbert-Schmidt decomposition with exactly one non-zero $\lambda_i$, that is **a single state** is enough to resolve the potential operator.

For a **local potential** we can see that the Hilbert-Schmidt expansion will require **all states from the position basis**. In formulae $$\langle r|V|r'\rangle = V(r) \delta(r-r') = \sum_{r''} V(r'') \langle r|r''\rangle \langle r''|r'\rangle.$$

So in this sense the separable potential is the opposite of the local one. If you actually want to call a one-state Hilber-Schmidt decomposition 'maximally non-local' depends on your definition of the latter term.